# How to align one axis in a two axis chart

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I want to align my right vertical scale with my left vertical scale so both have the 0 at the same height.

I have this:

[image: sample graph 1]

And I want this (I've done it manually but it's not perfect, look how both 0s are almost at the same line):

[image: sample graph 2]

Is there a way to do this automatically in Google Sheets?